# How can I move multiple folders that contain specific word in the name to another directory in linux?

Tags: linux, move

I have a directory Dir in which I have about 30 sub-directories. From these 30 sub-dirs there are about 20 with name dir_date and the other 10 with some random names. I want to move all the directories that contain dir in their names to another directory which could be created under Dir using the command line. I am using CentOS 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terminal, you can simply do

```
mv *dir* /example/location
```

where *dir* is a pattern that matches anything containing "dir". Fix the pattern to match your needs.

This will move all files containing "dir" in the directory you are in (in terminal, type pwd to check your current directory).

Comment: and this will move only folders that are in my current directory?

Comment: @inb Yes. you can also specify the directory, example:

mv /home/user/Dir/*dir* /example/location/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your directory name is "Dir"

Now **Dir** has 30 sub directories of which 20 starts with name "dir".

Lets say the other directory you want to create in **Dir** where you want store the files is "abc"

Thus, the following command:

```
mkdir Dir/abc
mv Dir/dir* Dir/abc
```

thats all ;)